# How do I get out of the "continuous pages" mode?

Tags: pages

How do I get out of the "continuous pages" mode?

It annoys me like hell! I want to see whole pages with a bit of space around them.

Is this another thing that iWork 13 can't do?

Just a one pixel line separating different pages in image below.
[image: Just a one pixel line separating different pages]

Comment: poking around in the app it doesn't look like there is a way to do this.

Comment: A hack would suffice. I'm no stranger to binary patches.
Bounty will only be awarded to the solution, not information that it is not possible which is what I suspected.

Answer (score 3):

**This is currently not possible.** The gap between pages is not customisable and it is not possible to disable continuous scrolling.

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this at the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/pages.html

Comment: Just as I thougth. A hack would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Just turn on Facing Pages in Document Tab and, after turning it on, change the zoom to one page.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually works!

Answer (score 0):

One way to give it some kind of "page view" could be to enable the "Show Layout" option. It give you a view with header, footer and margins shown.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't increase the space between pages, nor the space around the page (it decreases it unless you increase the size of the window)…

Comment: Yeah you're right about the space between the pages, but it doesn't decrease the page, it just show the editable area. To change the space around the page, you need to change the "Document Margins"

Comment: I meant the grey background space behind (therefore around) the page, not the margins of the actual page.

Comment: This grey background is not affected in my version of Pages (v5.2), when I enable the Layout option, so I don't know what you refer to ??

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**--------------- OR ---------------**

[image]

Comment: Hello Elaine! Welcome here!
What version of Pages are you using? I can't see this option for expanding white space.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to view (not edit) you could do Print/PDF/Open PDF in Preview